# execute prod, development builds from command line

Tags: gradle

I want to exclude one module during a development build but for a production build add it.

In `settings.gradle` I have:

```
if (!this.hasProperty("-cart-view")) {
   println("module prod")
   include 'cart-view'
}
else {
    include 'cart-api-service'
    include 'cart-cache-api'
    include 'cart-cache'
    println("In dev")
```

}

The above will print `module prod` but when I do:

```
gradle -x cart-view build
```

I get an error saying:

`* What went wrong: Task 'cart-view' not found in root project 'cart-checkout-parent`'.

Comment: `cart-view` seems to be a `project` not a `task`.

Comment: @ToYonos that is correct, it is a submodule.

Comment: So what are you expecting with `-x cart-view` ?  This option is meant to skip a task

Comment: @ToYonos I want to exclude one module during a development build but for a production build add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, what you want is :

```
// production
gradle build

// dev
gradle -P-cart-view build
```

Comment: I did try this before and it still printed out in `module prod` but when I remove the `!` it will move to the else statement (naturally)

Comment: Weird, I tried and it worked for me. `gradle -P-cart-view build` did set the property `-cart-view`